# Does db-owner has the permission to create users?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

How can I **create** a **`user`** which has the **`permission to create`** users in SQL Server?

I created a user with **`db-owner`** role but when I try to create new users it says that I **don't have sufficient permissions**.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Permissions required for 'CREATE USER' in SQL Server 2005?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/372834/permissions-required-for-create-user-in-sql-server-2005)

Comment: **[Refer this link](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/12/27/sql-server-add-any-user-to-sysadmin-role-add-users-to-system-roles/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two types of principals in SQL Server:

- A **server-wide login**.  A login is required to connect to the database server.  It stores the users credentials.  Rights on server privileges, and membership in server roles, are assigned to a login.
- A **database-specific user**. One user is always linked to one login.  A user is required to switch to a database with `use [dbname]`.  Rights on stored procedures, views, and membership of database roles are assigned to a user.

[Creating a user](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173463%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) requires `alter any user` permission, or membership of the `db_accessadmin` or `db_owner` database roles.  A database owner is a member of the `db_owner` role by definition.

[Creating a login](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189751%28v=sql.90%29.aspx) requires the `alter any login` privilege.  By default, that's granted to logins in the the `sysadmin` or `securityadmin` server role.

Comment: Creating a user does not require database ownership. Assuming a login already exists, a database user only has to have `db_accessadmin` or `ALTER ANY USER` in order to add a user to the database. Of course, further permissions may be required to add them to certain roles.

Comment: @AaronBertrand: Thanks, the "requires ownership" part was a quote from the [linked MSDN page.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms181422%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)  I'll update the answer.

Comment: fair, but you should link to [`CREATE USER`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms173463(v=sql.90).aspx) and [`CREATE LOGIN`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms189751(v=sql.90).aspx) documentation, instead of `sp_adduser`/`sp_addlogin` - which are deprecated.

Comment: but i ended up creating a server wide login with sysadmin role and it also have access to db objects as opposed to what you wrote. or did i not get it right?